# C UDP Client-Server stuck comunication

Tags: c, udp, client-server

for one of my university courses I must realize a simple chat program in C that uses UDP Client-Server, this is the description that the teacher sent us:

> You should develop a private chat environment to exchange
> *text messages* between hosts. Message encryption is optional but not required.
> The project should be composed by 2 main modules:
>
> - Server: receives and stores each message in a sort of chat *database*.
>   A very naive database would consist in a `User` struct,
>   that contains everything (login credentials, chats, ...).
>   Each `Chat` structure contains the actual messages.
> - Client: provides a very simple interface to select a
>   receiver for our message and then write the content of the message.
>   Login is required. If a receiver is not *subscribed* returns an error.

> The project should be tested with at least 3 users :)

I managed to implement the authentication phase but then when trying to implement the message exchange phase I got stuck. When I try to send the linked_list of online users from the Server to the Client the execution freezes and not only that but it gives somewhat of random behavior, sometimes gets stuck on the first try sometimes on the second and so on. I also noticed that when I introduced a separated thread in the Client to handle the inbox of messages the situation got worst getting stuck more often then before. I will add the code of the functions responsible of sending and receiving the online users and also the link to my git repo where if you want you can find the complete code.

This is the code in the Server:

```
void Send_list(ListHead* head, int sockfd,struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, int size){
int written_bytes;
int len = sizeof(cliaddr);
char username[50];


if(head->size == 1){
    return;
}

ListItem* aux = head->first;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    memset(username,0,sizeof(username));
    UserListItem* uitem = (UserListItem*) aux;
    strcpy(username,uitem->user.username);
    do{
        written_bytes = 0;
        written_bytes = sendto(sockfd,(const char *)username,strlen(username),0,(const struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,len); 
    }while(written_bytes != strlen(username));
    printf("\nusername mandato: %s",username);
    printf("\n");
    if(aux->next){
        aux = aux->next;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the code in the Client:

```
int recv_list(int sockfd,struct sockaddr_in  servaddr, ListHead* head,int size, char username[50]){

char onuser[50];
int len = sizeof(servaddr);
int read_bytes;
int idx = 1;   

if(size == 1){
    return 1;
}

for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    
    read_bytes = recvfrom(sockfd,(char *)onuser,sizeof(onuser),0,(struct sockaddr*)&servaddr,&len );
    onuser[read_bytes] = '\0';
    if(List_find_by_username(head,onuser) == 0 || strcmp(onuser,username)){
        UserListItem* uitem = malloc(sizeof(UserListItem));
        memset(uitem,0,sizeof(UserListItem));
        UList_init(uitem,onuser);
        uitem->idx = idx++;        
        ListItem* result = List_insert(head,head->last,(ListItem*)uitem);
        assert(result);
    }
    memset(onuser,0,sizeof(onuser));   
    
}


UserList_print(head);
return 0; 
}
```

And this is the link to my git repo:  https://gitlab.com/antonio_ciprani/so-progetto-20_21

I work in an Ubuntu based system.

I really hope that somebody can help me because this is driving me crazy :(

Comment: What happens of `sendto` returns with an error (when it returns `-1`)?

Comment: I also recommend you take this time to learn how to *debug* your programs. Like using a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude are you suggesting that the freezing happens duo to the lack of control over the sendto result? Also I tried using Valgrind and gdb but i didn't manage to understand where the problem exactly  happens only that is in these two functions

Comment: If `sendto` fails once and returns `-1`, it will continue to fail and return `-1`, leading to an infinite loop. Which will make it seem like your program "gets stuck".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you, i've done what you suggested adding a break statement in case of -1 result and worked fine untill i have uncommented the code for the inbox thread in the client and as soon as i've done it everything stopped working, i've check and added control over sendtos and recvfroms but didn't seem to work, do you might know why this happened?

Comment: It's impossible to tell. Please post a new question about that new issue, with details about it (and preferably a proper [mre]).

Comment: @Antonio Ciprani - How do you know that you _managed to implement the authentication phase_?

Comment: @Armali because i've tested it and works or so at least seems to me, did you find something that i missed ?

Comment: It didn't work on a perhaps peculiar system, but does work on another, so I don't doubt that it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also noticed that when I introduced a separated thread in the Client to handle the inbox of messages the situation got worst getting stuck more often then before.

Indeed the use of threads in your program does more harm than good. Especially that in the `main` loop you `pthread_create` a new `reciving` thread, which competes with the main thread for the incoming messages, disrupts the course of `recv_list`. Better don't use threads for your project - you'll avoid a lot of problems.

Let's first write two helper functions:

```
void store(thread_args_t *targs, Message *msg)
{   // code taken from your function "reciving"
    if (!strcmp(targs->user->username, msg->reciver))
    {
        Inbox *mitem = malloc(sizeof (Inbox));
        strcpy(mitem->msg.sender,  msg->sender);
        strcpy(mitem->msg.reciver, msg->reciver);
        strcpy(mitem->msg.data,    msg->data);
        ListItem *result =
            List_insert(targs->inbox, targs->inbox->last, (ListItem *)mitem);
        assert(result);
    }
}
```

```
char *input(thread_args_t *targs)
{   // wait for user input and store incoming messages
    fflush(stdout);
    fd_set fds, fdr;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(0, &fds);                // add STDIN to the fd set
    FD_SET(targs->sockfd, &fds);    // add socket to the fd set
    for (; ; )
    {
        if (fdr = fds, select(targs->sockfd+1, &fdr, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0)
            perror("select"), exit(1);
        if (FD_ISSET(0, &fdr))
        {   // this is the user's input
            static char data[256];
            if (!fgets(data, sizeof data, stdin)) return NULL;  // no more user input
            data[strlen(data)-1] = '\0';
            return data;
        }
        // if no user input, then there's a message
        Message msg;
        socklen_t len = sizeof targs->servaddr;
        if (recvfrom(targs->sockfd, &msg, sizeof msg, 0,
                     (struct sockaddr *)targs->servaddr, &len) < 0)
            perror("recvfrom"), exit(1);
        store(targs, &msg);
    }
}
```

Now you can replace the main loop body in `main` with this:

```
        int ret, op;
        printf("\nPlease choose an option: ");
        printf("\n1.Send a message!");
        printf("\n2.Incoming messages!");
        printf("\n3.Logout!");
        printf("\nYour choice:\t");
        char *str = input(&targs);
        sscanf(str, "%d", &ret);
        printf("\nqua bro?\n");
        if (ret == 1)
        {
            printf("\nqua loz?\n");
            int res, read_bytes, size, id;
            op = 3;
            socklen_t len = sizeof servaddr;
            sendto(sockfd, &op, sizeof op, MSG_CONFIRM,
                   (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, len);
            printf("\nqua shiiis?\n");
            // We cannot preclude that a message arrives here,
            // therefore we must handle that case.
            Message msg;
            while ((read_bytes = recvfrom(sockfd, &msg, sizeof msg, 0,
                                          (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,
                                          &len)) == sizeof msg)
                store(&targs, &msg);
            if (read_bytes == -1) perror("recvfrom"), exit(1);
            size = *(int *)&msg;
            printf("\nqua ci siamo?\n");
            res = recv_list(sockfd, servaddr, &on_list, size, user.username);
            printf("\nqua?\n");
            if (res == 0)
            {
                printf("\nChoose whom you want to send a message to");
                printf("\nYour choice:\t");
                str = input(&targs);
                sscanf(str, "%d", &id);
                printf("\nWrite the message you want to send:\n");
                str = input(&targs);
                Init_msg(&msg, str, id, &on_list, user.username);
                int written_bytes = sendto(sockfd, &msg, sizeof msg, MSG_CONFIRM,
                                           (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, len);
                if (written_bytes == -1) perror("sendto"), exit(1);
                // With your present server, a message cannot arrive here, but you
                // possibly will want to change that, so let's handle it already.
                while ((read_bytes = recvfrom(sockfd, &msg, sizeof msg, 0,
                                              (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,
                                              &len)) == sizeof msg)
                    store(&targs, &msg);
                if (read_bytes == -1) perror("recvfrom"), exit(1);
                int sent = *(int *)&msg;
                if (sent == 0) printf("\nMessage sent!");
                else
                if (sent == 1) printf("\nUser is offline :(");
            }
            else
            if (res == 1) printf("\nNo online user :(");
        }
        else
        if (ret == 2) Print_msg(&inbox);
```

The next thing you possibly want to improve is modifying the server function `Forward_message` so that it allows for incoming commands from another client while waiting for a message.

Comment: Okay, i kinda guessed that they were competing but i think that i really need a separate thread to handle the `inbox` otherwise i wouldn't be able to receive messages from other users asynchronously, do you know of a way to implement `reciving` without this occurring?

Comment: If you want _to receive messages from other users asynchronously_, why do you have the menu option `2.Incoming messages!`?

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by _asynchronously_?

Comment: The second option is to show the stored messages, by asynchronously I mean that you can receive a massage at any time you are connected also while writing a massage to some else or idling in the menu option. English is not my main language i hope i explained it correctly

Comment: Yes, you made it clear. I'm afraid I don't want to think about a convoluted way to implement concurrent receiving of different messages by multiple threads from the same sender. Are you interested in a different approach despite your thinking that you _really need a separate thread_?

Comment: Yes I'm really interested in a different approach, I'm not fixated on using multiple threads the only important thing is achieving the end result i need  using C

Comment: I expanded the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, you can't imagine how much you helped me right now. It's working really fine and I will give some thought on how to implement the suggestion on the last part of your answer. I really appreciate it, again thank you so much

Comment: if it is possible can I ask you a question on your approach? I know you already helped me a lot but one thing I can't understand about it

Comment: Of course you can ask - after all it's my fault if I didn't comment enough. ;-)

Comment: No no, not your fault it's me whose lacking knowledge. You have added many `recvfrom` to read incoming messages in specific points so that they don't interfere with other `recvfrom` or so I think, but to my knowledge standard `recvfrom` should be blocking so why even when we have one online user or no incoming message the execution doesn't stall?

Comment: Let's have a look on each one of those `recvfrom`s. The one in `input` is only called if `select` reports that socket input is ready, so it won't block. The first one in the main loop is called after the list of connected clients has been requested from the server, and it is called only until a server response other than a message (i. e. with `size`) is received (which must occur provided that the server is functioning), so this won't block any longer. The other one is called after a message has been sent, and it is called only until a server response (`sent`) is received, so won't block long.

Comment: Oh, yes now I get it really something that i couldn't even think of. You opened me a world Thanks again for the further explanation. You made it really clear and helped me a lot, probably more than you think :D